# Issue with Button Revealing Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem with revealing an image using a button; the image already appears, without clicking the designated button, when the pages loads.

I've tried:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<style> 

  body {
  background-image: url("a2_page_3.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<script>
  function showImage() {
    document.getElementById("stipends").style.display="";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="stipends" src="a2_page_3_1.PNG" style="diaplay:none;"/>
  <input type=button value="Produce Stipends" onclick="showImgage()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for all your input in advance!

Comment: Check the image id stipends again. You misspelled display as "diaplay." Good luck, everything else looks good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 typos: `showImgage()` in your button should be `showImage()` and   `diaplay:none` in your image should be `display: none`

Here's it working with jsut those 2 chages (and a cat image added in place of your image)

```html
<HTML>
<head>
<style> 

  body {
  background-image: url("a2_page_3.JPG");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<script>
  function showImage() {
    document.getElementById("stipends").style.display="";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="stipends" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgetwallpapers.com%2Fwallpaper%2Ffull%2Ff%2F3%2Fa%2F807159-download-funny-cats-wallpapers-1920x1200-meizu.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" style="display:none;"/>
  <input type=button value="Produce Stipends" onclick="showImage()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function showImage() {
    document.getElementById("stipends").style.display="";
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="stipends" src="a2_page_3_1.PNG" style="display:none;"/>
  <input type=button value="Produce Stipends" onclick="showImage()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally to the misspelling of display, as I commented, you misspelled the function showImage() as "showImgage()" in the button "onclick" statement.

Comment: Whoops! John beat me to that typo there by half a minute. Didn't see it until my page refreshed.